# Is there a feat that can change ability damage dealt by a creature's special attacks to ability drain?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, encounter-design, animals, monster-design

Recently, to my dismay, I discovered that my longstanding understanding of the Dire Weasel's Blood Drain ability was incorrect.  As Blood Drain deals Constitution *damage*, the weasel does not gain temporary hp.  Unfortunately, the temporary hp gain is rather important in a couple of modules I run recurrently, and so I am seeking a feat from somewhere in 3.5's vast body of first party sources (including *Dragon* and *Dungeon*) that would allow the ability damage to instead be ability drain (and thus grant 5 temporary hp/round per victim attached to).  Does such a feat exist?  I desire a feat, as opposed to other sources, because replacing the Dire Weasel's Alertness feat with such a feat would impact the use of such a monster least, while e.g. spells, magic items, etc require either additional HD in class levels for the weasel or an outside source (i.e. a friendly druid) currently not present in the most important weasel-based module I run.

Comment: I've created the 'monster-design' tag because I really think that it should exist and it is very applicable to this (and many other) questions.  Monster design is separate from encounter design in that a good monster is usable in a wide variety of encounters, with differing circumstances making things different.  It's different from Character creation cause that's about PCs.  It's different from game-design because that's mostly about the overall system.  It's different from homebrew because that umbrellas a lot of stuff and I wanna be more specific. Just in case you were upset by the new tag

Comment: Are you including *Dragon*?  Because outside of that, I am fairly sure no such feat exists. My sense is that even there, it wouldn't pass an editor, but they did publish some crazy stuff. Ability drain is much more powerful than ability damage, and its use is especially unbalanced between Team PC and Team Monster.

Comment: @fectin yeah, Dragon (and Dungeon) are ok.

Comment: Would you be willing to expand the question's mandate beyond official material? (Not that I have anything, of course, but because I hate answers that are just *No.*)

Comment: @HeyICanChan "No, but here's some stuff that doesn't quite fit your criteria but is close" is always a better answer than "No".  If the answer is "No", though, I'd rather ask another question than change this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No feat turns ability *damage* into ability *drain*

I've a document that I compiled for personal use that has, I think, all of the official feats, including feats from licensed sources. It runs over 2,500 pages, but that's including all my notes. Nonetheless, all told, it probably contains, like, *four thousand* feats, and while I won't claim that I've *actually* caught them *all*, I'd like to think I *almost* have and that any remaining omissions are from sources *so* obscure no one has them anyway.

With that in mind, I can say with a great deal of confidence that *no* feat transforms a creature's ability damage into ability drain. In fact, no feat even comes close. The effect ability drain is, of course, *mentioned* by several feats like Detach (*Savage Species* 32-3), Empowered Ability Damage (*Libris Mortis* 26), Inheritor (*Dragon* #315 70), Pawn in the Great Game (*Dragon* #354 56), Shriveling Touch (*Ghostwalk* 38), and Tainted Construction (Expanding Your Mind Web column ["Subpsionics"](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/pse/20021025a)), but ability drain is usually mentioned in the context of bonuses to resist ability drain, restrictions on the use of ability drain, or the creature gaining a unique ability drain effect—often with such a feat having *very* strict prerequisites (q.v. Shriveling Touch).

So, yeah, I'm almost sure you're sunk. I mean, it's possible, for example, for a psion to use the power [*astral construct*](http://dndsrd.net/psionicPowersAtoC.html#astral-construct) and, with the feat Tainted Construction, grant that astral construct an ability drain attack… and were that a psion to possess a sufficient Craft (sculpting) skill bonus, the psion could make that astral construct appear to be a weasel or dire weasel. But that's exactly *not* what you want.

The closest you may get is the domain feat Death Devotion (*Complete Champion* 57)—which seems to fit well with weasels as described in [your campaign](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/100589/8610)—that allows a typical weasel 1/day for 1 min. to cause foes struck by its melee weapon (its bite likely qualifying) to make Fort saves that, if failed, causes a foe to gain a negative level. Even the effect of the Death Devotion feat, however, isn't true [energy drain](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/67680/8610), so while the weasel, during that minute, *will* shred the heck out of, like, 10 commoners (and, tomorrow night, they'll become wights—weasels *can* still be jerks!), your weasels *still* won't have the special attack [ability drain](http://dndsrd.net/monsterTypes.html#ability-score-loss).

I suspect you must venture beyond official material for your weasel needs.

Comment: compiled resources... *drools*... oh for want of a properly compiled resource, my campaign will surely fail.... ^^